# USB serial devices not showing in /dev/serial/by-id/ after update from 21.04 to 21.10

Tags: usb, udev, serial-port

Architecture is arm64 running on a RPi 4 2gb. The serial device is any of my 3d printer boards running Klipper firmware.

USB device was working perfectly fine before update. I've also tried a fresh install of 21.10 to make sure it wasn't an update issue, but still having the same problem.  Installing a fresh copy of 20.04 LTS fixes the issue, so I'm fairly confident the issue is related to some change from 21.04 to 21.10.

Device shows up properly in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1d50:614e OpenMoko, Inc. lpc1769
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but the actual device (`/dev/ttyACM0` in 21.04 and 21.10) does not ever show up.

I'm not sure if it's related, but systemd-udevd seems to be throwing errors:

````
Oct 23 13:28:50 Himari systemd-udevd[931]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:14 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0;elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi'" for PROGRAM (char 58: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.
Oct 23 13:28:50 Himari systemd-udevd[931]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:27 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if [ -e /dev/ttyAMA0 ]; then exit 1; elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0;elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi'" for PROGRAM (char 97: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.
Oct 23 13:28:50 Himari systemd-udevd[931]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pi-bluetooth.rules:38 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial0; then echo 0; elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial1; then echo 1; else exit 1; fi '" for PROGRAM (char 58: invalid substitution type), ignoring, but please fix it.```
````

Comment: Does the USB go directly to the 3D printer, or via a USB->Serial adapter? In lsusb, which device is the 3D printer?

Comment: USB directly to the printer board.
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1d50:614e OpenMoko, Inc. lpc1769` is the serial device

Comment: Have you looked at /var/log/syslog for any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Please check if **linux-modules-extra-raspi** package is installed. Looks like some drivers were moved into a new package in 21.10 to reduce the size of the initramfs. Installing it manually helped in my case:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
sudo reboot
```

---

I am also affected by the exact same issue. Earlier today, I was working and setting up an USB IR reader for my power meter with Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. After `do-release-upgrade`, the /`dev/ttyUSB0` did not show up. The USB device in `lsusb` is there, but somehow the usbserial device creation does not kick in.

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6015 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Bridge(I2C/SPI/UART/FIFO)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Device in question is `0403:6015`.

There seem to be a related bug filed here already [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1947723).

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly the answer!

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much. I've spent all day trying to figure this out!